# Is the following code valid according to the HTML standards?

Tags: html

I want the 1 question on the bottom left and 2 links on the bottom right place at the same level.

```html
<p align="left"> Have a Question?
  <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=abc@gmail.com"> Ask me</a>

  <a href="https://google.com/">
    <image tag>
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com/">
    <image tag>
  </a>
</p>
```

This works fine for me but I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to do it or not.

Comment: This is not responsive so it's not acceptable in 2022.

Comment: Any suggestions? which tag can be used in place?

Comment: I want the link on a specific text and not the entire one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: https://codepen.io/ceejayoz/pen/RwQwGyP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this if you want the link to be left-aligned and the images to be right-aligned...

```html
<div style="width: 90%;">

  <div style="float: left;">
Have a Question?<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=abc@gmail.com"> Ask me</a>
  </div>

  <div style="float: right;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x20">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x20">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`align` is not a valid HTML attribute, and `<image tag>` is not a valid HTML element

Comment: My bad. What I meant from <image tag> was that there will be a <img> tag that I will be using here.